# creating pdf with itextsharp with images from database

Tags: html, database, image, pdf, itext

I have a process where the html is stored in database with image links. the images are also stored in db as well. I've created a controller action which reads the image from database. the path I'm generating is something like `/File/Image?path=Root/test.jpg`. 
this image path is embedded in html in img tag like `<img alt="logo" src="/File/Image?path=Root/001.jpg" />`

I'm trying to use itextsharp to read the html from the database and create a pdf document

```
string _html = GenerateDocumentHelpers.CommissioningSheet(fleetId);
string _html = GenerateDocumentHelpers.CommissioningSheet(fleetId);
Document _document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 80, 50, 30, 65);
MemoryStream _memStream = new MemoryStream();
PdfWriter _writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(_document, _memStream);
StringReader _reader = new StringReader(_html);            
HTMLWorker _worker = new HTMLWorker(_document);
_document.Open();            
_worker.Parse(_reader);
_document.Close();
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Commissioning.pdf");
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.OutputStream.Write(_memStream.GetBuffer(), 0, _memStream.GetBuffer().Length);
Response.OutputStream.Flush();
Response.End();
return new FileStreamResult(Response.OutputStream, "application/pdf");
```

This code gives me an illegal character error. this comes from the image tag, it is not recognizing ? and = characters, is there a way I can render this html with img tag so that when I create a pdf it renders the html and image from the database and creates a pdf or if itextsharp can't do it, can you provide me with any other third party open source tools that can accomplish this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the image source isn't a fully qualified URL including protocol then iTextSharp assumes that it is a file-based URL. The solution is to just convert all image links to absolute in the form `http://YOUR_DOMAIN/File/Image?path=Root/001.jpg`.

You can also set a global property on the parser that works pretty much the same as the HTML `<BASE>` tag:

```
//Create a provider collection to set various processing properties
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object> providers = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>();
//Set the image base. This will be prepended to the SRC so watch your forward slashes
providers.Add(HTMLWorker.IMG_BASEURL, "http://YOUR_DOMAIN");
//Bind the providers to the worker
worker.SetProviders(providers);
worker.Parse(reader);
```

Below is a full working C# 2010 WinForms app targeting iTextSharp 5.1.2.0 that shows how to use a relative image and set its base using the global provider. Everything is pretty much the same as your code, although I through in a bunch of `using` statements to ensure proper cleanup. Make sure to watch the leading and trailing forward slashes on everything, the base URL gets prepended directly only the `SRC` attribute and you might end up with double-slashes if its not done correctly. I'm hard-balling a domain in here but you should be able to easily use the `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request` object.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string html = @"<img src=""/images/home_mississippi.jpg"" />";
            string outputFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "HtmlTest.pdf");
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
                using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.TABLOID)) {
                    using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs)) {
                        doc.Open();

                        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(html)) {
                            using (HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(doc)) {
                                //Create a provider collection to set various processing properties
                                System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object> providers = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>();
                                //Set the image base. This will be prepended to the SRC so watch your forward slashes
                                providers.Add(HTMLWorker.IMG_BASEURL, "http://www.vendiadvertising.com");
                                //Bind the providers to the worker
                                worker.SetProviders(providers);
                                worker.Parse(reader);
                            }
                        }

                        doc.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Chris, since your code is inside "using", is it really necessary the doc.Close() ?

Comment: You are correct, I just like my commands to balance each other. If I explicitly use open then I like to explicitly use close. Personal preference.