# Generating PDF using itestsharp

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, pdf, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to generate a pdf file using itextsharp.

Here is the method that's supposed to generate the PDF:

```
private void Page_onPreRenderComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // createPdf.GeneratePDF(htmlMarkup);
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sBuilder);
    HtmlTextWriter htmlText = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    Page.RenderControl(htmlText);
    string pdfBody = sBuilder.ToString();

    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);

    document.Open();
    StyleSheet styles = new StyleSheet();
    HTMLWorker hw = new HTMLWorker(document);

    try
    {
        hw.Parse(new StringReader(pdfBody));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       string msg = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        document.Close();
    }

    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=outfile.pdf");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(memoryStream);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

an error is generated on the line within the try block. How can I fix this?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: "The network path was not found.\r\n"

Comment: `HTMLWorker` was replaced by `XmlWorker` a long time ago and it is recommended that you switch to that. In the mean time, please see this which shows how to set relative image paths: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9484217/231316

Answer (score 0):

may be the image tags etc are in relative paths instead of absolute paths in the rendered HTML