# itextsharp error generated when parsing html

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, itext

Good day,
Ive just started working with itextsharp to generate pdfs. I keep getting an error when i try to do so. But when i generate the pdf in an override of the render method it seems to work..

This is the code on the button click:

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string htmlMarkup = createPdf.GetHtmlPage(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);

    try
    {
        createPdf.GeneratePDF(htmlMarkup);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblmessage.Text = ex.Message;
        throw;
    }
}
```

And the code in the generate class:

```
    public void GeneratePDF(string pdfBody)
    {


        var document = new Document();

        // TODO : Write to Memory Stream
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memStream);

        document.Open();
        iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet styles = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
        iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker hw = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(document);

        //Why is this line not working??
        hw.Parse(new StringReader(pdfBody));

        document.Close();

         ShowPdf();
    }

    public string GetHtmlPage(string strURL)
    {

        String strResult;
        WebResponse objResponse;
        WebRequest objRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL);

        objRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        objRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
        objRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            strResult = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
        }
        return strResult;
    }
```

The error is generated at the commented line. The error is "The network path was not found.\r\n" How can i fix this?! 
Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating PDF using itestsharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564858/generating-pdf-using-itestsharp)

Comment: Please edit the original question instead of creating a new one. Thanks