# How to convert webpage to pdf file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-to-pdf

I want to convert my webpage by button on click in codebehide i will receive that url and finally it will convert webpage to pdf and save it in to my specific path.Can u suggest the easy tool(dll files) to convert webpage by url website. please Thank you so much

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert HTML to PDF in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net)

Comment: Did you find any tools/libraries yourself?

Comment: i want to use wkhtmltopdf but i can't file code example.Are you show me ?

Comment: refer this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957268/wkhtmltopdf-convert-html-code-to-pdf-directly-in-c-sharp

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34898467/1453867

Answer (score 0):

[PDFsharp](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=27&Itemid=1)

> **Key Features**
>
> - Creates PDF documents on the fly from any .Net language
> - Easy to understand object model to compose documents
> - One source code for drawing on a PDF page as well as in a window or on the printer
> - Modify, merge, and split existing PDF files
> - Images with transparency (color mask, monochrome mask, alpha mask)
> - Newly designed from scratch and written entirely in C#
> - The graphical classes go well with .Net